# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un estado mediante un context?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente al intentar pasar un estado para verificar si un usuario esta logeado o no.

Al principio en mi App js pasaba el estado como prop y desde el child component lo mandaba al componente padre actualizado. Era algo así.

App.js

```
function App() {

      return (
          <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={isLoggedIn ? <Dashboard/> : <Login/>}/>
            <Route  path="/" element={<Login  setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} />} />    
          </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
        
      );
```

Y en mi Login.js recibía el estado y lo mandaba actualizado.

```
const Login = ({ setIsLoggedIn }) => {

   function handleCallbackResponse(response){
        var userData = jwt_decode(response.credential); //Token with the login user Data
        setUser(userData); //Store user Data 
        setIsLoggedIn(true)
        /* console.log(userData) */
        document.getElementById('signInDiv').hidden = true;
        
      }
   
   useEffect(()=>{
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id:"186813496344-0j9cjp3klq5igcsk8a2vcdm5gcosner8.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          callback: handleCallbackResponse
        })
    
        google.accounts.id.prompt();
    
    
        window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
          document.getElementById('signInDiv'),
          {theme: 'outline', size: 'medium'}
        )
    
      }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <div id="signInDiv"></div>
      {
        //If user objetc is not empty show sign out button
        Object.keys(user).length !== 0 &&
      <button onClick={(e)=>handleSignOut(e)}>Sign Out</button>
      }
      {user && 
        <div>
          <img src={user.picture} alt="" />
          <h3>{user.name}</h3>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

El tema es que ahora realicé un context para poder usar mis variables en distintos componentes, pero no sé cómo pasar el estado ahora.

Mi App.js quedó así:

```
import './App.css';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Login from './atoms/Login';
import { BrowserRouter , Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import { LoginProvider } from './LoginContext';


function App() {

  

  return (
    <LoginProvider >
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
        <Route  path="/" element={<Login />} />    
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </LoginProvider>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Mi Login.js:

```
/*global google*/
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import LoginContext from '../LoginContext'; 

const Login = () => {

   const {user, handleCallbackResponse, handleSignOut} = useContext(LoginContext);   
   
   useEffect(()=>{
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id:"186813496344-0j9cjp3klq5igcsk8a2vcdm5gcosner8.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          callback: handleCallbackResponse
        })
    
        google.accounts.id.prompt();
    
    
        window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
          document.getElementById('signInDiv'),
          {theme: 'outline', size: 'medium'}
        )
    
      }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <div id="signInDiv"></div>
      {
        //If user objetc is not empty show sign out button
        Object.keys(user).length !== 0 &&
      <button onClick={(e)=>handleSignOut(e)}>Sign Out</button>
      }
      {user && 
        <div>
          <img src={user.picture} alt="" />
          <h3>{user.name}</h3>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Y este sería mi context llamado LoginContext.js, donde creo un context, lo exporto con la variable user y las funciones handleCallbackResponse y handleSignOut

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

const LoginContext = createContext();

export function LoginProvider({children}) {

    const [user, setUser] = useState({}) 
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn ] = useState(false)

    function handleCallbackResponse(response){
        var userData = jwt_decode(response.credential); //Token with the login user Data
        setUser(userData); //Store user Data 
        setIsLoggedIn(true)
        /* console.log(userData) */
        document.getElementById('signInDiv').hidden = true;        
      }

    function handleSignOut(event) {
        setUser({}) //Empy the user Data
        document.getElementById('signInDiv').hidden = false;
    }  

    return(
        <LoginContext.Provider value={{user, handleCallbackResponse, handleSignOut}}>{children}</LoginContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default LoginContext
```

Ahora yo no sé cómo de esta manera usando un Context puedo pasar de mi App un estado para que ese estado sea actualizado en mi LoginContext.js y vuelva actualizado a mi App.js para poder hacer luego una redirección condicional con mis rutas.